# Remote Python Shell

Tags: python, remote

I'm teaching my friend how to program in Python. So far, we have been using Skype's screen sharing feature, but that is quite cumbersome and low resolution. Is there a way we can have a common shell or command window? Both of us should be able to type within it and execute code. Any ideas?
We both are using Win7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a common server that has GNU `screen` installed, and run:

`screen -S myScreenName`

Have the other person log in as the same user and execute:

`screen -x myScreenName`

You can then run the Python interpreter inside `screen`. Both members will see the same thing, and both will be able to type.

Comment: Err, any solutions for Win7?

Comment: It would be highly appropriate to add a reference to Cygwin if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: You'll probably either have to use Cygwin, either SSH into a Unix server. It shouldn't be too bad however, since the Python interpreter works the same on both Windows and Unix. If you need to do anything using the win32 API Python bindings though, that won't really work.

Comment: @VenkateshH is this useful to you: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx

Comment: Hmm, I'll try both, cygwin (with GNU Screen) and as @joaquin says, Remote Desktop Access. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/). But i'm not sure about less cumbersome.